# How to generate an Excel file based on MYSQL columns using Laravel

Tags: mysql, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I want to generate an Excel template based on the column of a MySQL database.
I want  the worksheets to be the columns of the Excel file.

How can I achieve that. I am using Laravel

Comment: I'm adding a comment on top of the answers. I have personally tried with Maatwebsite & fast-excel which is based on Spout. Maatwebsite Excel is a good library with ease-to-use feature. However, Fast-excel could overcome performance issue with the use of generator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Maatwebsite](https://packagist.org/packages/maatwebsite/excel)

It's an excellent package to use excel sheets in Laravel. Go through it's documentation

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is off-topic for SO. Therefore, answers that only provide library recommendations should also be avoided. This is more suitable as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Spout Excel,

Spout is capable of processing files of any size and it only  needs 3MB of memory to process any file.

I've tested it generating exporting a data from database and importing excel file to database, and so far so good.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31371554)

Answer (score -1):

You should look for a library that does that for you on Packagist.

For example, with [maatwebsite/excel](https://packagist.org/packages/maatwebsite/excel), here is a summary of the quick start guide:

1. Create an exporter (automatically as shown or manually as in the doc)

```php
php artisan make:export UsersExport --model=User
```

2. Call it where you need it:

```php
Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'users.xlsx');
```

3. Look for `users.xlsx` in `/downloads`

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is off-topic for SO. Therefore, answers that only provide library recommendations should also be avoided. This is more suitable as a comment.

Comment: I do know how to export, but my question is how to I export a table data to Excel sheet @tomishap